# How to escape percent sign (%) in \path or \texttt environment?

Tags: errors, paths, typewriter, percent-sign

How to escape [percent sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent_sign) (`%`) in `\path{...}` or in `\texttt{...}`?

For instance compiling this code fails since `%` sign starts comment:

```
\path{%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts}
```

The result of escaping `%` sign:

```
\path{\%SystemRoot\%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts}
```

is:

```
\%SystemRoot\%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

How to solve the problem?

---

### Update

The problem is caused by `\footnote`. Minimal **not** working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
Hi!\footnote{%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Erh, `\path{%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts}` works just fine when you remember to load the `url` package. Do please tell us where you got `\path` from if it was not from the `url` package.

Comment: In general, please make self contained examples, we are fresh out of magic crystal balls.

Comment: Sorry. This issue comes from quite complex and huge master thesis, but I made minimal **not** working example. See [update](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337323/how-to-escape-percent-sign-in-path-or-texttt-environment#question).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\path` of package `url` directly supports percent characters, unless it is used inside arguments of other macros. `\path` (or `\url`) changes the category codes of special characters before and for reading its argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% for \textbackslash inside \texttt

\begin{document}
\path{%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts}

\texttt{\%SystemRoot\%\textbackslash system32\textbackslash drivers%
  \textbackslash etc\textbackslash hosts}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

`\texttt` can also be used, but special characters are more cumbersome. The percent character can be generated by `\%` (or `\@percentchar`, which needs `\makeatletter`). The backslash can be given in text mode by `\textbackslash`. Font encoding `T1` fixes the outdated `OT1` encoding with respect to the backslash in the typewriter font family.

### Path in footnotes

`\urldef` works fine, the update section of the question misspells the command: `\hostspath` vs. `\hostpath`. Also, there are two invisible Unicode characters inside `hosts`: U+200B ZERO WIDTH SPACE and U+200C ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER. The corrected version with corrected macro name and removed garbage characters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\urldef\hostpath\path{%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts}

\begin{document}
% \vspace*{\fill} % only for smaller image for answer
Hi!\footnote{\hostpath}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with \urldef and path in footnote]

Comment: The problem is that I use `\path{%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts}` in `\footnote` and it doesn't work.

Comment: @patryk.beza There's `\urldef` for that matter: you define a path and assign a name to a path, and then use the symbolic name to call it. Better approach, less option to have an error, and easy to change at one place and then all the symbolic calls are automatically showing what you want: `\urldef\hostspath\path{%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts}` and then use `\hostspath` wherever you want.

Comment: Nice to know @Manuel, but it doesn't solve the problem. See my original post [update](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337323/how-to-escape-percent-sign-in-path-or-texttt-environment#question).

Comment: @patryk.beza `\urldef` works. The example of the update section in the question only breaks because of several typos.

Comment: You are right. Thank you @Manuel and @HeikoOberdiek!

Answer (score 4):

here's an approach that depends on plain tex techniques.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\begingroup
\catcode`\%=13
\gdef\mypath{\path{%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts}}
\endgroup

\begin{document}
%Hi!\footnote{\path{%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts}}
Hi!\footnote{\mypath}
\end{document}
```

[image]